# Loading Image while service gets data using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my application in login page i want loading image with message "Loading" in xamarin forms before the service gets data. 
[image]

For that i used Activity indicator like this:

```
 ActivityIndicator indicator = new ActivityIndicator { Color = Color.Blue, };
        indicator.IsRunning = false;
       indicator.IsVisible = false;
        indicator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        indicator.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
```

and after click on Login button,I added code like this

```
  indicator.IsRunning = true;
  indicator.IsVisible = true;
```

now i am getting loading image only and in the same screen.But i want like the above image.can anyone suggest me to solve this.
                                        Thanks in advance

Comment: You could place both the ActivityIndicator and the Image in the same spot, and let the Image be invisible until you're ready show all of it. Then when making the Image visible, you make the ActivityIndicator and Label invisible.

Comment: Are they placed in a grid or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following library for the Dialogs
It supports Xamarin.Forms aswell

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

**EDIT 1**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    **using Acr.UserDialogs;**
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Splat;

    namespace ProjectScreen
    {

        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public ObservableCollection<MainPageViewModel> projects { get; set; }
            public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection _connection;
            public bool IsLoading;
            public MainPage()
            {
                projects = new ObservableCollection<MainPageViewModel>();
                InitializeComponent();
                this.getConnection();
                foreach (Project Pname in this.GetProjects())
                {
                    projects.Add(new MainPageViewModel { Name = Pname.name  });
                    lstView.ItemsSource = projects;
                }
                AddNewItem.Clicked += (o, s) =>
                {
                    this.PromptCommand();
                };
                lstView.ItemSelected += LstView_ItemSelected;
            }

            private void LstView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
            { 
                    **UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading data");**
                    Task.Run(() => { waitForMinute(); });
            }

            private async void waitForMinute()
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                **UserDialogs.Instance.Loading().Hide();**
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new ProjectDetails()));
                });
            }
}
}
}
```

Lines indicated with ** are for AcrDialog You can use them in any file as per your requirement

make Sure you run them on main thread

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using Acr.UserDialogs Package but i am getting errors.Please Guide me how to use that package for Loading Message in xamarin forms

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working.Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: The above code is working fine in ios but in android it is not working and even i added this line **UserDialogs.Init(this);** in main activity.